# Transparency layering in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I am working on an automotive project and the client wants me to show a translucent model of a car on top of the engine assembly. The issue is with transparency layering of cycles. I know cycles is making it look the proper way but is there any hack to make it look like the result in the material preview?

[image: Materal Preview Mode]
**Material preview**

[image: Cycles preview]
**Cycles**

I have tried backface culling, but that does not work in this case. Is there any hack to do this in Cycles?
Setting up view layers and doing this in compositing seems to be an overkill. This means I would have to set up Holdout layers and much more. Any simple hack for this??

Comment: Do you have to do it in _Cycles_? Why not use _Eevee_ because that's the engine for the material preview as well...?

Comment: Well, the project is completely set up for cycles. And that quality is needed too. Rest of the shots are already rendered in cycles.

Comment: I don't even see what you want to achieve. In the _Material Preview_ there is only the cube slightly transparent, everything else seems opaque? By the way, translucency is not transparency.

Comment: So the engine will come under the body where the cube is present. At present, cube is opaque. Only body has to be made semi transparent. Just faded on top of engine.

Answer (score 3):

For Cycles, an Option would indeed be the compositor with one view layer for the car (shading **without transparency/alpha** - imho the *Velvet BSDF* does very well) and another layer for the motor.

The compositing is not that heavy:

[image]

With the two annotated sliders, you can fine-tune the 'fading' of Car and Motor separately.

Comment: Thank you. This could also work. Will check this out!

Comment: @ArunBabu I thought you said in your question this would be overkill? That's why I asked how exactly you want it, because I excluded this as possible solution.

Comment: Hi. Finally I did it with compositing itself. I said overkill because there were a lot of background and foreground objects. So I had to set up holdout layers and all (which was a lengthy outliner cleanup and organisation) But if some hack was available for this, it wouldn't have been necessary. But it's fine for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Principled Shader for your materials, the Principled's Alpha value does quite a nice job of it:

[image: Principled Alpha]

To reproduce that with any other shader, you can simply mix whatever shader tree you have with a Transparent BSDF Shader:

[image: Transparent BSDF]

You can even have fun with it and add a little bit of flavor to your transparency:

[image: fun transparency]

To add backface culling in Cycles, you can mix the Geometry node's Backfacing data as a factor to another mix shader with transparent shader:

[image: backfacing setup]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have tried this. Here in this case i actually don't want transparent objects to layer up. In eevee, apart from backface culling, there is a show backface toggle. That disables layering of transparency. Only first transparent layer is rendered. Is something similar available in cycles? A hack?

Comment: You can recreate backface culling in Cycles yes, i added it in my answer. But it will not occlude frontfacing geometry that is behind (I.E. here the monkey's ears will remain visible even if "hidden" by the head, only the insides are). Editing my answer.

Comment: @L0Lock If backface culling in _Eevee_ is okay for Arun, your _Cycles_ version should be, too... _Eevee_'s backface culling would show the opposite ear as well.